# When crafting with the ironwood spell, are the effects permanent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Ironwood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ironwood) spell has a very defined duration, but the [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) skill has the following line in its description;

> A successful Craft check related to woodworking in conjunction with
>   the casting of the ironwood spell enables you to make wooden items
>   that have the strength of steel.

Furthermore, the Ironwood spell description has this line;

> Using this spell with wood shape or a wood-related Craft check, you
>   can fashion wooden items that function as steel items. Thus, wooden
>   plate armor and wooden swords can be created that are as durable as
>   their normal steel counterparts. These items are freely usable by
>   druids.
>
> Further, if you make only half as much ironwood as the spell would
>   normally allow, any weapon, shield, or suit of armor so created is
>   treated as a magic item with a +1 enhancement bonus.

Both of these lines imply that Ironwood can, and should be used during item creation.

Here's where my confusion begins.

If the spell runs out, and can be recast on the wooden item, what purpose does it serve to use it during item creation?

I could just buy wooden armor, then cast it, and recast it over and over.

So my theory would break down the spell into two situations as follows;

1) If using Ironwood on a wooden item it has a duration.  For example, buying wooden armor and having to cast Ironwood on it over and over again to keep it strong.

2) If using Ironwood while creating a wooden item the effect is permanent.  The spell becomes an integrated property of the item.

I'm wondering if there is anything in RAW that explicitly states that what I'm suggesting is wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the effects of the spell [*ironwood*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ironwood) aren't permanent nor does the spell [*permanency*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency), as printed, allow *ironwood* to be *made* permanent (although a DM "may allow [it] to be made permanent" as an unlisted *other* spell, probably at a cost of 15,000 gp like other 6th-level spells (e.g. [*symbol of fear*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-fear), [*symbol of persuasion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-persuasion))). That means you're absolutely correct in your assessment of the weirdness and nigh-uselessness of the spell. The only thing that I can figure is that...

## The Game Makes Assumptions

Other than niche uses, such as a *Magnificent Seven* (or *Three Amigos*) scenario in which fortifications must be made to defend the town against an attack that's coming within the next few days (but not *today* because a 6th-level spell is *meaningful* and better spent), the spell *ironwood* is just a bad spell.

The problem is the game's assumptions. First, the game assumes the best armor normally available for a druid is hide armor. Second, the game assumes the druid *must* be completely self-sufficient, making *everything*--including the *best* armor--by himself out in the wild.

These aren't *unreasonable* assumptions, by the way, but they are *flawed* for most games. If the first is untrue *ironwood*'s a dumb spell, and if the second is untrue *ironwood*'s a useless spell.

### The Druid Can Wear Better Armor

Even if no other options are available, the special material [dragonhide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Dragonhide) can be used to make [dragonhide plate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/dragonhide-plate), which functions as masterwork [full plate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/full-plate), so a druid needn't use the spells *ironwood* and *wood shape* to make a suit of full plate unless he's lost his dragonhide plate, which is difficult in combat (although not *impossible*--there are ways to strip him of it) or the culmination of a convoluted series of events out of combat.

A druid might *feel better* having crafted his own armor, even if he must use his highest level spell every 11 days to renew the armor's effect, and I guess that's important. The only real reason I can see for a druid to do so is if the campaign world excludes or makes exceedingly rare special materials like dragonhide, forcing the druid who wants to wear another kind of armor besides hide or leather to find another source for that better armor. And, dude, that source is, like, *totally* nature.

### The Druid Can Buy Better Armor

The *Player's Handbook* for *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* didn't include dragonhide and other special materials; those were in a separate *Dungeon Master's Guide*. Thus it was possible for druids in that game to never even know of the existence of dragonhide armor or any of the myriad other kinds of armor better than hide they could wear. *Pathfinder*, by moving special materials into the chapter Equipment alongside daggers, 10-ft. poles, and spell component pouches, eliminated any mystique surrounding such items and eliminated--possibly--a major reason for the spell *ironwood*.

## "Why's this spell even here?"

That's a really good question, and I can't even speculate very well. The spell *ironwood* doesn't appear in the *Player's Handbook* for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* nor *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, Second Edition*. It *does* appear in the *Wizard's Spell Compendium* for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, Second Edition*, but its description calls wizards *wu jen* and notes that the spell is "[c]ommon in oriental [sic] settings; very rare elsewhere" (469), which leads me to believe that it originally appeared (the *Wizard's Spell Compendium* being a collection of previously published spells) in either *Oriental Adventures* for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* or an *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, Second Edition* source covering the same material, but I can't speak to that.

The *ironwood* spell in the *Wizard's Spell Compendium* is a 5th-level alteration spell with a touch range, a 1-round casting time, a permanent duration, and an *Area of Effect* entry of 1 cubic foot per level. It grants that affected wood "the tensile strength... of the finest steel" (468). If it's used on a living plant, the plant continues to grow metal leaves and bark. If used on a plant creature, the creature's paralyzed if it fails a saving throw. So in older editions it's mainly a toy--a useful tool for DMs to explain why a wizard has steel trees in his garden and other weird decorations (there were a lot of spells like that in older editions) and as a sit-back-and-watch item for the DM to put on a scroll that the PCs will find, just to see what sort of shenanigans they'll try with the spell. DM fiat played a much larger role in spell adjudication in the game's older versions.

But, as can be seen, this older version of the spell *ironwood*--with its permanent duration and affecting a *cubic foot of wood per level*--would be a lot more fun and useful than the version *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition*--and, eventually, *Pathfinder*--saddled us with. I've no idea Jonathan Tweet's intent when he chose this previously obscure spell for inclusion in the *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* core rules yet rewrote it to be largely useless.

Answer (score 3):

It does have a duration, yes. Eventually your armor returns to being wood.

There are a few things here that are relevant, as to why you would create the armor specifically with the *ironwood* spell. As a material, wood is not great for armor; making the wood behave like metal opens up additional options *for its construction*. For example, you cannot make wood chain, because wood cannot be bent or fused into loops like metal can. This rule allows you to make armors from the wood that you ordinarily could not make of wood at all.

Secondly, there is the option of making the armor have a +1 enhancement bonus by using less material than you’re entitled to. That option is unavailable to a suit of wooden armor that you later cast *ironwood* on.

Note that you can re-cast *ironwood* on the armor to reset the duration.

Comment: Little late on this, but the +1 enhancement bonus applies even if the wooden armor was created before casting ironwood. The only condition is that the wood weight be half of what you're able to transform to ironwood, which is 5lbs/(caster level). Meaning if the items weighs 2.5lbs/(caster level) or less you get a +1 enhancement bonus on it.